# how can i deserialize xml in C#

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, deserialization, xml-deserialization

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization; 
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace PlaylistEditor.Writers
{
    public class XMLPlaylistWriter : IPlaylistWriter
    {
        public void Save(Playlist ply, string filePath)
        {
            StreamWriter writer = null;
            try
            {
                XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(ply.GetType());
                writer = new StreamWriter(filePath);
                xs.Serialize(writer, ply);

            }
            finally
            {
                if (writer != null)
                    writer.Close();
                writer = null;
            }
        }


        public Playlist Load(string filePath)
        {
          return null;    

        }


    }
}
```

I wrote to load "return null;" i serialized that and ran code, but i can't do and find how to deserialize. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `XmlReader`.

```
private Playlist Load(string filename)
{
    Playlist playlist;
    // Create an instance of the XmlSerializer specifying type and namespace.
    var serializer = new
    XmlSerializer(typeof(Playlist));

    // A FileStream is needed to read the XML document.
    using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(fs))
        {
            playlist = (Playlist) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
    return playlist;
}
```

reference from msdn => [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz8csy73(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @HimBromBeere Thanks for pointing to that silly mistake. Updated method return type. :)

Comment: Change `i` to anything else, add a `finally` (or even better, `using`), and you're good to go.

Comment: @YoryeNathan You are right. `FileStream` and `XmlReader` are IDisposable so wrap then with using statement